# Filtering on a calculated field - Filter being ignored

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I have spent a couple of days (no joke) trying to get a filter to work.  I have two calculated fields in a list query.  They are called totalFY and countFY, respectively.  Here are the expressions for the fields:

totalFY: total ([Hard Credit] for [Constituent ID], [Date of Record Fiscal Year])

countFY: count (distinct [Date of Record Fiscal Year] for [Constituent ID])

When I drag totalFY to the detail filters panel, and set a threshold (let's say, >5000), my list query turns out the expected results, which would be customers whose total purchases for each year are greater than 5000.

But when I add the countFY field to the filter panel, it is completely ignored by the filter threshold I set (in this case, >2).  I've tried several things over the past couple of days and am really stumped.

If I filter with only one or the other, each works fine independently.  I've tried setting one to "apply filter after auto aggregation" but I get the same results.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.  What I ended up doing was creating a new query and adding countFY from the previous query as a data item in the new one.  Now I can filter effectively on countFY, and adjust the totalFY amount filter in the previous query.  Hope this helps someone else out there.